# How can I find different areas of triangles from a list of points?

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

If I have a list of points such as `{{1, 1}, {4, 7}, {24, 67}, ..., {17, 83}}`, how can I find the area of triangles formed by different combinations of these points? For example, what code would I need to find the area of the triangle formed by `{{1, 1}, {4, 7}, {24, 67}}` (but for all possible combinations)? Can I do this using a loop? I really have no idea where to even begin with this, any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

To calculate a single triangle area,we can use

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {4, 7}, {24, 67}};
Triangle[pts] // Area
(* 30 *)
```

To calculate all the triangles, we need to use `Subsets` to get all the `3` combination.

```
list = {{1, 1}, {4, 7}, {24, 67}, {17, 83}};
Triangle /@ Subsets[list, {3}] // Area
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this a function? So we could do this for an arbitrary amount of points (if we don't automatically see the number of combinations)? @cvgmt

Comment: @anonymous4554 `triArea[pts_] := Area[Triangle /@ Subsets[pts, {3}]];
triArea[{{1, 1}, {4, 7}, {24, 67}, {17, 83}}]`